# Loading Model Error using Pixellib in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, model, mask

For context, I am running an apple silicon mac and have used the rosetta terminal + miniconda to create a venv that runs python 3.7.

Here is the code I am trying to run.

```
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

segment_image = instance_segmentation()
segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
```

And this is the error below. I think it may be due to issues with the access to the GPU but I cannot be sure. Have been working on it for a few days.

```
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USERNAME/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
  File "/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/envs/cowsUpdate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixellib/instance/__init__.py", line 65, in load_model
    self.model.load_weights(model_path, by_name= True)
  File "/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/envs/cowsUpdate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixellib/instance/mask_rcnn.py", line 2110, in load_weights
    hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, layers)
  File "/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/envs/cowsUpdate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 718, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue when using tf.keras.models.load_weights(), and I downgrade h5py from 2.10 to 2.8.0 in tensorflow 2.0.0, then it works, maybe you can have a try.